# Flatten list of lists by one Level in Groovy without mutating variables

Tags: list, groovy, flatten, purely-functional

Imagine a list of lists, for example

```
List lists = [[[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]], [[5]], [[6]], [[7]], [[8]], [[9]], [[10]]]
```

This is just an example - the inner lists may contain multiple elements. I want to flatten the list by one level without mutating variables. The result should be

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```

Is there a good way in Groovy for that? It should be almost as fast as

```
lists.inject([]) { a, b -> a.addAll(b); a }
```

- `lists.flatten()` flattens across all levels, resulting in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.
- `lists.sum()` is concise and does the job, but sadly in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* for this case. It should be done in *O(n)*.
- The Java Streams way `lists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).toList()` seems to be *O(n)* in Groovy, but I was'nt so sure at first as it apparently comes with an extreme overhead compared to using it directly in Java. You can speed it up by a factor of 10 to 100 by just wrapping it in a method using `@CompileStatic`. Then it would be fast, but that is not really a convenient solution. There must be another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, apparently that is what `lists.collectMany { it }` is for...

`collectMany()` is a bit like `flatMap` in Scala or Java Streams.
It does not mutate variables at top level and is reasonably fast:
Not as fast as

```
lists.inject([]) { a, b -> a.addAll(b); a }
```

but much faster than

```
lists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).toList()
```

I have played around with it and `collectMany()` is more powerful than the standard `flatMap` and pretty cool to use, also for concatenating Maps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The power of my upvote :)